# Whenever I am trying to enter an address in my input Field , it automatically changes to one particular address only

Tags: dapp-development, addresses, react

My input field code

`<input type="text" placeholder="Enter address" onChange={(e)=>oppaddrchange(e)}/>`

And my handler function

```
const oppaddrchange = (e)=>{
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

The handler function will print whatever  I type until I hit a valid address in the field. As soon as I enter a valid address it will automatically change to this address
**0xf4b10f8D6F2659C0Eb2c2F559F62Fd90f0E853d6**. No matter what address I input, it will result in the same. When I copy-paste it anywhere on my screen, it works fine. I also tried to enter the address without copy-paste, but the address automatically changes.

What's wrong happening here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it's really not related to Ethereum. You should ask this as a generic question in some React forum

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to ethereum. It seems to be a problem with the browser being manipulated from an extension or a malware.

Answer (score 1):

i got a similar issue once and i realized it was a virus, its possible your browser got hacked so that whenever you type an address it will paste the attacker address so that all funds are transferred to him.

Comment: Even I thought so at first. A default extension in chrome  was causing this problem . But I had never installed it by myself. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @MrBot no problem, could you upvote my answer, i need points to comment :=)